# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'customFileInput'

Tags: jquery, head

I have a problem loading my scripts, here's my index.html head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Thai Express</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.fileinput.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/thai-express.js"></script>

</head>
```

And here is the error I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'customFileInput'

Here's a sneak at the beginning of the file "thai-express.js" in which I get the error:

```
    //on page load call _js_init
jQuery(document).ready(ThaiExpress_js_init);

function ThaiExpress_js_init(){
    jQuery(".cf_upload").customFileInput(); // custom upload field

    jQuery("#footer-promo li h3, ul#footer-promo li a.icon").hover(function(){ // hover both items simultaneously
        jQuery(this).parent().find("h3 a, a.icon").addClass("hover");
    },function(){   
        jQuery(this).parent().find("h3 a, a.icon").removeClass("hover");
    });
```

I tried to change my scripts load order but I can't find a solution.

I think I found the source of the problem. I debugged it using Firefox and I found out that it never gets inside this function "jQuery.fn.customFileInput = function(){" but, I don't know how I could solve this. Here is the content of "jQuery.fileinput.js".

```
jQuery.fn.customFileInput = function(){
return jQuery(this).each(function(){
//apply events and styles for file input element
var fileInput = jQuery(this)
    .addClass('customfile-input') //add class for CSS
    .mouseover(function(){ upload.addClass('customfile-hover'); })
    .mouseout(function(){ upload.removeClass('customfile-hover'); })
    .focus(function(){
        upload.addClass('customfile-focus'); 
        fileInput.data('val', fileInput.val());
    })
    .blur(function(){ 
        upload.removeClass('customfile-focus');
        jQuery(this).trigger('checkChange');
     })
     .bind('disable',function(){
        fileInput.attr('disabled',true);
        upload.addClass('customfile-disabled');
    })
    .bind('enable',function(){
        fileInput.removeAttr('disabled');
        upload.removeClass('customfile-disabled');
    })
    .bind('checkChange', function(){
        if(fileInput.val() && fileInput.val() != fileInput.data('val')){
            fileInput.trigger('change');
        }
    })
    .bind('change',function(){
        //get file name
        var fileName = jQuery(this).val().split(/\\/).pop();
        //get file extension
        var fileExt = 'customfile-ext-' + fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        //update the feedback
        uploadFeedback
            .text(fileName) //set feedback text to filename
            .removeClass(uploadFeedback.data('fileExt') || '') //remove any existing file extension class
            .addClass(fileExt) //add file extension class
            .data('fileExt', fileExt) //store file extension for class removal on next change
            .addClass('customfile-feedback-populated'); //add class to show populated state
        //change text of button 
        uploadButton.text('Change');    
    })
    .click(function(){ //for IE and Opera, make sure change fires after choosing a file, using an async callback
        fileInput.data('val', fileInput.val());
        setTimeout(function(){
            fileInput.trigger('checkChange');
        },100);
    });

//create custom control container
var upload = jQuery('<div class="customfile"></div>');
//create custom control button
var uploadButton = jQuery('<span class="customfile-button" aria-hidden="true">Browse</span>').appendTo(upload);
//create custom control feedback
var uploadFeedback = jQuery('<span class="customfile-feedback" aria-hidden="true">No file selected...</span>').appendTo(upload);

//match disabled state
if(fileInput.is('[disabled]')){
    fileInput.trigger('disable');
}


//on mousemove, keep file input under the cursor to steal click
upload.insertAfter(fileInput); //insert after the input

fileInput.appendTo(upload);

});

};
```

Thanks

Comment: use either http or https, not both. Otherwise, I don't see anything that would make `customFileInput` undefined on `jQuery.fn` unless the plugin you are including doesn't define it.

Comment: Are you sure the file that implements `customFileInput()` is being included correctly and is accessible?

Comment: Yes it is accessible, I tried to use only http or https and that doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: I know this sounds redundant, given other comments, but, Check `console.log` and make sure that `js/jQuery.fileinput.js` is actually loaded. I really don't see why this wouldn't run. If not loaded correctly, Chrome's console will show you red text stating it couldn't locate that file and show you the full link so you can see where it's looking

Comment: Also, are you sure your plugin for `$.fn.customFileInput()` is written correctly? is it inside something like `(function($) { /* add plugin like: */ if (!$.fn.customFileInput) { $.fn.customFileInput = function(e) { /* do work */ } } /* end if statement of adding plugin */   })(jQuery);`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'customFileInput' thai-express.js:5

This is what I get in Chrome's console

Comment: Also, it sometimes helps to add an ext ';' or two at the beginning of a plugin file to catch code that might not have ended and is thus interfering. like `;;(function($) { ...`

Comment: I just edited if you guys have any new idea about this. Thanks